# Finding if two strings are anagrams in O(n) - solution using XOR

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm working on a problem from [hackerearth](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/basic-programming/input-output/basics-of-input-output/practice-problems/algorithm/two-strings-4/)

The goal is to find if the input strings are anagrams in O(n) time.

Input format:

- First line, contains an intger 'T' denoting no. of test cases.
- Each test consists of a single line, containing two space separated
  strings S1 and S2 of equal length.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    int T;
    std::cin >> T;
    std::cin.ignore();

    for(int i = 0; i < T; ++i)
    {
        std::string testString;
        std::getline(std::cin, testString);

        char test =  ' ';

        for (auto& token : testString)
        {
            if(token != ' ')
                test ^= token;
        }

        if (test == ' ')
            std::cout << "YES\n";
        else
            std::cout << "NO\n";
    }

}
```

The code above fails 5/6 hackerearth tests.
Where is my mistake? Is this a good approach to the problem?

Comment: `' '` is the integer value `32` in ascii. Are you sure that's what you want to use for the blank value of `test`?

Comment: Your program thinks `AA` and `BB` are anagrams.

Comment: @Justin if the strings are anagrams all other values should show an even number of times, so whatever the test value is it should be left unchanged.

Comment: Ah, thanks, @melpomene. if tokens are showing even number of times it will return true...

Comment: You can do the simplest solution – count the characters – in linear time.

Comment: It also thinks `AB` and `EF` are anagrams.

Comment: For anagrams, sort the characters in each string and compare.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Note:* Your question title says that the second word must be an *anagram* of the first. But, the linked to problem on hackerearth uses the term *rearranged*, which is more restrictive than an anagram and also says:

> Two strings S1 and S2 are said to be identical, if **any** of the permutation of string S1 is equal to the string S2

---

One algorithm is to maintain a histogram of the incoming chars.

This is done with two loops, one for the first word and another for the second word.

For the first word, proceed char-by-char and increment the histogram value. Calculate the length of the first word by maintaining a running count.

When the space is reached, do the other loop which decrements the histogram. Maintain a count of the number of histogram cells that reach zero. In the end, this must match the length of the first word (i.e. success).

In the second loop, if a histogram cell goes negative, this is a mismatch because either the second word has a char not in the first word or has too many of a char in the first word.

---

*Caveat:* I apologize for this being a C-like solution, but it can easily be adapted to use more STL components

Also, char-at-a-time input may be faster than reading in the entire line into a buffer string

**Edit:** I've added annotation/comments to the code example to try to make things more clear

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char buf[(200 * 1024) + 100];

void
dotest(FILE *xf)
{
    int histo[26] = { 0 };
    int len = 0;
    int chr;
    int match = 0;
    int fail = 0;
    int cnt;

    // scan first word
    while (1) {
        chr = fgetc(xf);

        // stop on delimiter between first and second words
        if (chr == ' ')
            break;

        // convert char to histogram index
        chr -= 'a';

        // increment the histogram cell
        cnt = ++histo[chr];

        // calculate number of non-zero histogram cells
        if (cnt == 1)
            ++len;
    }

    // scan second word
    while (1) {
        chr = fgetc(xf);

        // stop on end-of-line or EOF
        if (chr == '\n')
            break;
        if (chr == EOF)
            break;

        // convert char to histogram index
        chr -= 'a';

        // decrement the histogram cell
        cnt = --histo[chr];

        // if the cell reaches zero, we [seemingly] have a match (i.e. the
        // number of instances of this char in the second word match the
        // number of instances in the first word)
        if (cnt == 0)
            match += 1;

        // however, if we go negative, the second word has too many instances
        // of this char to match the first word
        if (cnt < 0)
            fail = 1;
    }

    do {
        // too many letters in second word that are _not_ in the first word
        if (fail)
            break;

        // the number of times the second word had an exact histogram count
        // against the first word must match the number of chars in the first
        // [and second] word (i.e. all scrambled chars in the second word had
        // a place in the first word)
        fail = (match != len);
    } while (0);

    if (fail)
        printf("NO\n");
    else
        printf("YES\n");
}

// main -- main program
int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    char *file;
    FILE *xf;

    --argc;
    ++argv;

    file = *argv;
    if (file != NULL)
        xf = fopen(file,"r");
    else
        xf = stdin;

    fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),xf);
    int tstcnt = atoi(buf);

    for (int tstno = 1;  tstno <= tstcnt;  ++tstno)
        dotest(xf);

    if (file != NULL)
        fclose(xf);

    return 0;
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> I've only had a glance at the code but it seems that len goes up for every char found (string lenght). and match goes up only when a unique char (histogram element) is exausted, so the check match == len will not be good?

`len` is only incremented in the *first* loop. (i.e.) It is the length of the first word only (as mentioned in the algorithm description above).

In the first loop, there is a check for the char being a space [which is *guaranteed* by the problem definition of the input to delimit the end of the first word] and the loop is broken out of at that point [*before* `len` is incremented], so `len` is correct.

The use of `len`, `match`, and `fail` speed things up. Otherwise, at the end, we'd have to scan the entire histogram and ensure all elements are zero to determine success/failure (i.e. any non-zero element means mismatch/failure).

*Note:* When doing such timed coding challenges before, I've noted that they can be pretty strict on elapsed time/speed and space. It's best to try to optimize as much as possible because, even if the algorithm is technically correct, it can fail the test for using too much memory or taking too much time.

That's why I suggested *not* using a string buffer because the maximum size as defined by the problem can be 100,000 bytes. Also, doing the [unnecessary] scan of the histogram at the end would also add time.

---

**UPDATE #2:**

It *may* be faster to read a full line at a time and then use a char pointer to traverse the buffer. Here's a version that does that. Which method is faster would need to be tried/benchmarked to see.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char buf[(200 * 1024) + 100];

void
dotest(FILE *xf)
{
    char *cp;
    int histo[26] = { 0 };
    int len = 0;
    int chr;
    int match = 0;
    int fail = 0;
    int cnt;

    cp = buf;
    fgets(cp,sizeof(buf),xf);

    // scan first word
    for (chr = *cp++;  chr != 0;  chr = *cp++) {
        // stop on delimiter between first and second words
        if (chr == ' ')
            break;

        // convert char to histogram index
        chr -= 'a';

        // increment the histogram cell
        cnt = ++histo[chr];

        // calculate number of non-zero histogram cells
        if (cnt == 1)
            ++len;
    }

    // scan second word
    for (chr = *cp++;  chr != 0;  chr = *cp++) {
        // stop on end-of-line
        if (chr == '\n')
            break;

        // convert char to histogram index
        chr -= 'a';

        // decrement the histogram cell
        cnt = --histo[chr];

        // if the cell reaches zero, we [seemingly] have a match (i.e. the
        // number of instances of this char in the second word match the
        // number of instances in the first word)
        if (cnt == 0)
            match += 1;

        // however, if we go negative, the second word has too many instances
        // of this char to match the first word
        if (cnt < 0) {
            fail = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    do {
        // too many letters in second word that are _not_ in the first word
        if (fail)
            break;

        // the number of times the second word had an exact histogram count
        // against the first word must match the number of chars in the first
        // [and second] word (i.e. all scrambled chars in the second word had
        // a place in the first word)
        fail = (match != len);
    } while (0);

    if (fail)
        printf("NO\n");
    else
        printf("YES\n");
}

// main -- main program
int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    char *file;
    FILE *xf;

    --argc;
    ++argv;

    file = *argv;
    if (file != NULL)
        xf = fopen(file,"r");
    else
        xf = stdin;

    fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),xf);
    int tstcnt = atoi(buf);

    for (int tstno = 1;  tstno <= tstcnt;  ++tstno)
        dotest(xf);

    if (file != NULL)
        fclose(xf);

    return 0;
}
```

---

**UPDATE #3:**

The above two examples had a slight bug. It would report a *false* negative on an input line of (e.g.) `aaa aaa`.

The increment of `len` was *always* done in the first loop. This was incorrect. I've edited the above two examples to do the increment of `len` conditionally (i.e. *only* if the histogram cell was zero before the increment). Now, `len` is "the number of non-zero histogram cells in the first string". This takes into account duplicates in the string (e.g. `aa`).

As I mentioned, the use of `len`, `match`, and `fail` was to *obviate* the need to scan all histogram cells at the end, looking for a non-zero cell which means mismatch/failure.

This would [possibly] run faster for short input lines, where the post scan of the histogram took longer than the input line loops.

However, given that input lines can be 200k in length, the probability is that [almost] all of the histogram cells will be incremented/decremented. Also, the post scan of the histogram (e.g. check 26 integer array values for non-zero) is now a negligible part of the overall time.

Thus, the *simple* implementation [below] that eliminates `len/match` calculations inside the first two loops may be the fastest/best choice. This is because the two loops are slightly faster.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char buf[(200 * 1024) + 100];

void
dotest(FILE *xf)
{
    char *cp;
    char buf[(200 * 1024) + 100];
    int histo[26] = { 0 };
    int chr;
    int fail = 0;

    cp = buf;
    fgets(cp,sizeof(buf),xf);

    // scan first word
    for (chr = *cp++;  chr != 0;  chr = *cp++) {
        // stop on delimiter between first and second words
        if (chr == ' ')
            break;

        // convert char to histogram index
        chr -= 'a';

        // increment the histogram cell
        ++histo[chr];
    }

    // scan second word
    for (chr = *cp++;  chr != 0;  chr = *cp++) {
        // stop on end-of-line
        if (chr == '\n')
            break;

        // convert char to histogram index
        chr -= 'a';

        // decrement the histogram cell
        --histo[chr];
    }

    // scan histogram
    for (int idx = 0;  idx < 26;  ++idx) {
        if (histo[idx]) {
            fail = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (fail)
        printf("NO\n");
    else
        printf("YES\n");
}

// main -- main program
int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    char *file;
    FILE *xf;

    --argc;
    ++argv;

    file = *argv;
    if (file != NULL)
        xf = fopen(file,"r");
    else
        xf = stdin;

    fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),xf);
    int tstcnt = atoi(buf);

    for (int tstno = 1;  tstno <= tstcnt;  ++tstno)
        dotest(xf);

    if (file != NULL)
        fclose(xf);

    return 0;
}
```

The downside is that there is *no* "early escape" from the second loop. We would have to finish the scan of the second string even though we might be able to tell early that the second string can't match (e.g.):

```
aaaaaaaaaa baaaaaaaaa
baaaaaaaaa bbaaaaaaaa
```

With the simple version we couldn't terminate the second loop early even though we know the second string can never match when we see the `b` (i.e. the histogram cell goes negative) and skip over the scan of the multiple `a` in the second word.

So, here's a version that has a simple first loop as above. It adds back the on-the-fly check for a cell going negative in the second loop.

Once again, which version [of the four I've presented] is the best needs some experimentation/benchmarking.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char buf[(200 * 1024) + 100];

void
dotest(FILE *xf)
{
    char *cp;
    int histo[26] = { 0 };
    int chr;
    int fail = 0;
    int cnt;

    cp = buf;
    fgets(cp,sizeof(buf),xf);

    // scan first word
    for (chr = *cp++;  chr != 0;  chr = *cp++) {
        // stop on delimiter between first and second words
        if (chr == ' ')
            break;

        // convert char to histogram index
        chr -= 'a';

        // increment the histogram cell
        ++histo[chr];
    }

    // scan second word
    for (chr = *cp++;  chr != 0;  chr = *cp++) {
        // stop on end-of-line
        if (chr == '\n')
            break;

        // convert char to histogram index
        chr -= 'a';

        // decrement the histogram cell
        cnt = --histo[chr];

        // however, if we go negative, the second word has too many instances
        // of this char to match the first word
        if (cnt < 0) {
            fail = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    do {
        // too many letters in second word that are _not_ in the first word
        if (fail)
            break;

        // scan histogram
        for (int idx = 0;  idx < 26;  ++idx) {
            if (histo[idx]) {
                fail = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    } while (0);

    if (fail)
        printf("NO\n");
    else
        printf("YES\n");
}

// main -- main program
int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    char *file;
    FILE *xf;
    char buf[100];

    --argc;
    ++argv;

    file = *argv;
    if (file != NULL)
        xf = fopen(file,"r");
    else
        xf = stdin;

    fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),xf);
    int tstcnt = atoi(buf);

    for (int tstno = 1;  tstno <= tstcnt;  ++tstno)
        dotest(xf);

    if (file != NULL)
        fclose(xf);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I've only had a glance at the code but it seems that len goes up for every char found (string lenght). and match goes up only when a unique char (histogram element) is exausted, so the check match == len will not be good?

Comment: @AntonioDropulić I've updated my answer to include some more explanation and added comments to the code example to help clarify things.

Comment: What is the difference between "anagram" and "rearranged"? Do you bring that up because "anagram" often implies both sequences are an English (or some other language) word or phrase?

Comment: @aschepler Partially. An anagram _usually_ reuses the letters exactly once, but it is _not_ required to [as stated in the linked problem statement, which is more precise]. From wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anagram _Anagrams don't necessarily have to use all the letters, but they normally do._  But, the linked problem page _does_ allow [seemingly] nonsense words that can be 50k bytes long. And there are only _two_ per line and they are the _same_ length. Anagrams, however, can change the number of words: adultery :: true lady

Answer (score 0):

```
public static final int ASC = 97;

static boolean isAnagram(String a, String b) {
    boolean res = false;
    int len = a.length();
    if (len != b.length()) {
        return res;
    }
    a = a.toLowerCase();
    b = b.toLowerCase();
    int[] a_ascii = new int[26];
    int aval = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2 * len; i++) {
        if (i < len) {
            aval = a.charAt(i) - ASC;
            a_ascii[aval] = (a_ascii[aval] == 0) ? (aval * len + 1) : (a_ascii[aval] + 1);
        } else {
            aval = b.charAt(i - len) - ASC;
            if (a_ascii[aval] == 0) {
                return false;
            }
            a_ascii[aval] = a_ascii[aval] - 1;
            res = (a_ascii[aval] == aval * len) ? true : false;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```